# Why is it necessary to perform a server-side build for TypeScript or NestJS-based applications?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, build, nestjs

While deploying backend applications, especially those built with TypeScript and NestJS, it's often recommended to undergo a build process before deployment. This practice, analogous to frontend build processes (e.g., "npm run build"), might seem counterintuitive for traditional Node.js applications that can be directly started using tools like PM2.
So i am intereted to get to know the main reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

nodejs doesn't support typescript, and you want to use typescript. That's why, right?

but you can do this with nodejs 20:

[image]

(actually, I don't think this is good for production)

Comment: no, the question is why i will have to create build after using typescript. we can deploy as it is at server.

Comment: you can deploy as it is to the server, I didn't follow what you're asking. You just can't run typescript code on server with nodejs as you can with Deno and Bun.

Comment: thanks for your interest. question was simple. we can run typesript based backend code at server. then why we need to create its build.

Comment: I just said you can't run typescript on server with Nodejs. If you're using Deno or Bun, yes you can. No need to perform a build beforehand in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons to build TypeScript applications, and I have mentioned some of them.

**Compilation and Performance:**
Ahead-of-Time (AoT) Compilation: Nest.js uses TypeScript, and the build process involves transpiling TypeScript to optimized JavaScript for efficient execution on Node.js in production.

**Environment Isolation:**
Running TypeScript code directly with tools like ts-node is common during development for convenience. In production, using a compiled build ensures isolation from development tools and dependencies.

**Dependency Injection:**
The build process eliminates unused dependencies through tree-shaking, reducing the size of the final output.

**Enhanced Security:**
The build process can include code obfuscation and security best practices to protect against reverse engineering.

**Optimization and Bundling:**
Bundling and minification during the build process reduce network latency and improve load times in production.